# Differences between 性能試験 and 強化試験

Tags: word-choice, nuances, business-japanese, computing

In the same meeting, I heard people talking about [性能試験](http://wa3.i-3-i.info/word13744.html), and then about [強化試験](https://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/bote_bote163/470804.html), like it was a totally different thing.

My understanding is that both are software performance tests. What are the differences or nuances in usage between the two?

Comment: The liked blog post about 強化試験 sums it up perfectly: "言葉通り本来計画していないテストを追加で行うこと". ...wait, what?

Comment: 「評価試験 evaluation test」と言ったのを聞き違えていませんか。「性能試験」という言葉はありますが、「強化試験」という言葉は日本語として意味が確立していません。もし聞き違いがなければ貴社独特の意味があると思いますので、一般的な回答は期待できないでしょう。なお、評価試験には、「性能評価試験」「耐久性評価試験」のように一般に「ＸＸ評価試験」のようにＸＸのところに評価したい機能や項目名のようなものが入ります。

Comment: software performance testと言ってますので違うと思いますが、もしハードウエア関係の影響がある会社か職場で「強化試験」と言う場合があるなら、「耐久試験 endurance test」をより短期間におこなうための「加速試験 accelerated test」のような意味で「強化試験」を使っているかもしれません。

Comment: software performance testを含めシステムの目標性能に対する余裕度を調べるための「過負荷試験 overload test」も「強化試験」と言う組織があるかもしれません。

Comment: @mackygoo: 今もう一回聞きましたが、やはり「強化試験」ですね。分野はソフトウェアです。独特とはいえ、ググるとソフトウェア品質の業界のウェブページが結構出てきます。

Comment: もしよければ，Nicolas Raoul さんの職場ではどのような意味で使われているかご紹介ください。因みに私のコメントに記載した用語は個別の企業によらず標準的に通用する用語です。

Comment: >ググるとソフトウェア品質の業界の‌​ウェブページが結構出てきます。 定義が示されない「強化試験」という曖昧な表現で品質向上を図れると判断している業界というより管理体制の職場では、定量的な品質確保のための試験は出来ていないと判断できます。結論として「強化試験」と言う言葉は日本語として無理して理解する必要はないと断言できます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

性能試験 is simply performance test, and is used widely in many fields related to engineering, including software engineering.

I don't think 強化試験 is a common term, but judging from usages found on the net, it seems to refer to additional tests to ensure something (performance, conformance, stability, etc) You may need to ask your colleagues what 強化試験 actually refers to in your company.

Comment: sounds like "stress test" to me

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Maybe yes, but that's usually 耐久(性)試験 or ストレステスト.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, 性能試験 is a performance test. If it's a server side, checking how many connections can be handled or how long it takes to return a response. Mainly focusing to know its performance. But the case of 強化試験, It's for finding bugs. And it's not a regular test like unit tests nor integration tests. It simply means a additional test for finding bugs. in another way to say, it is a test of 強化(quality enhancement)